# Pinterest and Google+ Share buttons won't open from inside an iframe

Tags: html, iframe, google-plus, tumblr, pinterest

I have a tumblr site where each post has share button for Facebook, Twitter, Pinterest, Google+, and email. They are all supposed to open in a new window. Facebook and Twitter do, but Pinterest, G+ and email which open in the same window.

This tumblr site will live in an iframe on the company's main site. From the main site, the Pinterest, G+, and email links don't open at all. They don't do anything. Facebook and Twitter links have the same behavior as behavior as before; they work.

Here's the html I'm using for the links:

```
    <ul>
         <li class="open-in-app"><a href="#" class="share-item open-in-app" data-post="{PostID}">Open in app</a></li>
         <li><a href="http://facebook.com/sharer.php?u={URLEncodedPermalink}&amp;t={URLEncodedTitle}" class="share-item facebook" target="_blank"><img src="http://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0248/9574/t/1/assets/productShareFB.png?7867"></a></li>
         <li><a href="https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text={URLEncodedTweetSummary}" class="share-item twitter" target="_blank"><img src="http://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0248/9574/t/1/assets/productShareTwitter.png?7867"></a></li>

         <li><a href="http://pinterest.com/pin/create/button/?url={URLEncodedPermalink}&amp;media={PhotoURL-HighRes}&amp;description=Isaora" class="share-item"><img src="http://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0248/9574/t/1/assets/productSharePinterest.png?7867"></a></li>
         <li><a href="mailto:?subject={URLEncodedShareString}&amp;body={URLEncodedMailSummary}" class="share-item mail"><img src="http://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0248/9574/t/1/assets/productShareMail.png?7867"></a></li>
         <li><a href="https://plus.google.com/share?url={URLEncodedPermalink}" class="share-item"><img src="http://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0248/9574/t/1/assets/productShareGPlus.png?7867"></a></li>
     </ul>
```

How do I:
 * get the email, pinterest and g+ links to work on the tumblr site is inside an iframe
 * get them to open in a new window.

Comment: your twitter and facebook links has a target=_blank attribute but the others doesn't, are you aware of that?

Comment: ah. i've been staring at this too long. thanks! sorry for wasting your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> get the email, pinterest and g+ links to work on the tumblr site is inside an iframe

You can't. They use HTTP headers to tell browsers they should not be opened in frames.

> get them to open in a new window.

The same way as the links which already open in a new window:

```
target="_blank"
```